# Integration and qualification tests for an application

Tags: integration-testing

I'm trying to realize a calculator using `JAVA`, so I'm following these stages:

1. Needs analysis (specifications)
2. UML diagrams
3. Programming
4. Unit testing
5. Integration and qualification tests

for Unit testing I'm using `JUnit` but I don't know what I'm gonna need to accomplish the fifth stage.

Answer (score 1):

Integration testing is the phase in software testing in which individual software modules are combined and tested as a group. You can use for this, for example, JBoss Arquillian (http://www.jboss.org/arquillian). Also can use Spring+JUnit for interaction with your application.